# htaccess or php redirect to this task?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need help from someone with experience :)

I have noticed that lot of sites with SEO friendly urls like www.site.com/123456/some-title only take the value 123456 and doesnt matter the rest, htaccess just send the variable 123456 to the specific url and then the visitor see the content.

So, if I type

1. www.site.com/123456/some-title-1
2. www.site.com/123456/some-title-2
3. www.site.com/123456/some-title-3
4. www.site.com/123456/some-title-4

I will always see the same page because the id passed is always the same 123456.

But I saw a few sites correcting this. For example:

-If I type any of the 4 urls above, they show me the content BUT they redirect me to the right url (www.site.com/123456/some-title) first.

How can I do that? I think this is a php question, since they need to connect to the database to check the original "url path" for the id 123456, right?

If someone can give me a tip to do that would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Please provide us your .htaccess aproach.

Comment: check this may be it helps you..[htaccess redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211396/htaccess-redirect-incomplete-task)

Comment: The magic word here is 'routing'. You see this a lot in frameworks like Cake, Ruby on Rails or Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do that? I think this is a php question, since they need to connect to the database to check the original "url path" for the id 123456, right?

This is a PHP question. 2 things need to happen here. When someone requests:

```
www.site.com/123456/some-title-1
```

There is routing that happens in htaccess, something like (example rules):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /some.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

So whatever the script is (some.php), it'll get two parameers, an ID  and a slug. The ID is what it uses to do a lookup into a database or wherever the actual content is stored. When it fetches that information from the database, it can compare slugs. If they differ, then instead of serving the content, redirect the browser to show the correct slug. Then we start back over from the beginning, browser submits request (this time with the right slug for the ID), rewrite rule routes it to `some.php` and because the slug is correct, the actual content gets served to the browser.